# Uploaded files are having same file size which is 15B when uploaded. I am using JQuery and azure-storage-blob.min.js version 12 to upload files to az

Tags: jquery, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I am trying to upload files to Blob container using jquery and I am using azure-storage-blob.min.js version 12. Below is my code. Here **fileToBeUploaded** is a json object with properties like size, name, ContentType and so on.

```
uploadFileToAzure: function () {
        var fileToBeUploaded = UPLOAD.DESTINATION_FILE_CONFIGURATION;            
        if (fileToBeUploaded != null && fileToBeUploaded.length > 0) {

            $.each(fileToBeUploaded, function (index, value) {
                const container = new azblob.ContainerURL(value.Url, azblob.StorageURL.newPipeline(new azblob.AnonymousCredential));
                try {
                    UPLOAD.log('sendFile');
                    $('form :input').attr('disabled', true);                       
                    const blobOptions = {
                        blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: value.ContentType },
                    };
                    const blockBlobURL = azblob.BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(container, value.Key);
                    var result = azblob.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(
                        azblob.Aborter.none, value, blockBlobURL, blobOptions);

                    result.then(function (result) {
                        alert("Done");
                        return true;
                    }, function (err) {
                        alert("Error");
                        console.log(err);
                        return false;
                    });


                } catch (error) {
                    alert(error);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**fileToBeUploaded** (With the below fileToBeUploaded object--> I am getting a 404 error. This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server.)

```
fileToBeUploaded[0]
e {id: 'o_1frjmofms1afu1ii2u4pc0c12kdj', name: 'Sample.ppt', type: 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', relativePath: '', size: 85504, …}
completeTimestamp: 0
destroy: ƒ ()
getNative: ƒ ()
getSource: ƒ ()
id: "o_1frjmofms1afu1ii2u4pc0c12kdj"
lastModifiedDate: Fri Oct 29 2021 12:34:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
loaded: 0
name: "Sample.ppt"
origSize: 85504
percent: 0
relativePath: ""
size: 85504
status: 1
type: "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

**fileToBeUploaded2** (With the below fileToBeUploaded2 object--> I am able to upload files to azure but the file size is 15B and this is happening for all the files. And when I try to download those files they are corrupted)

```
fileToBeUploaded2[0]
{Policy: null, Signature: null, Bucket: null, Key: 'xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/a67d27a4-b50c-40de-9818-bc5d5bb37b08.pdf', FileName: 'pdf-sample.pdf', …}
AccessKey: null
Acl: null
AmzAlgorithm: null
AmzCredentials: null
AmzDate: null
Bucket: null
ContentType: "application/pdf"
ExternalId: "2939"
FileName: "pdf-sample.pdf"
Key: "xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/a67d27a4-b50c-40de-9818-bc5d5bb37b08.pdf"
MediaUrl: null
ModuleId: 0
Policy: null
Signature: null
Type: 0
Url: "https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxxx?sv=2020-08-04&se=2022-02-12T07%3A14%3A34Z&sr=c&sp=w&sig=xxxxx"
UserAgent: null
size: 22260
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

My problem is when I try to upload any file to azure the file size remains the same. I confirmed it by going into the portal and checking each and every file which I have uploaded via jquery. And the file size is 15B and when I try to open any file it's corrupted. I have no issues with uploading and downloading. **My only issue is once it is uploaded the file is getting corrupted.**

Comment: What's the value of your `value` variable here - `$.each(fileToBeUploaded, function (index, value) {`?

Comment: Please edit your question and include `fileToBeUploaded` content in the question.

Comment: I have edited the question. For security reasons I have masked the sas signature and other stuff.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri any update?